# Docker build failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition

Tags: docker, curl, networking, dns

My docker build is failing with the following error:

```
#3 [internal] load metadata for pdr.akamai.com/library/tomcat9-java11:platform-2.19.4-RELEASE
#3 sha256:fe12d438fd0a4596fbe4a8af247e39a88858ee59a23a35a954fc8676153423fd
#3 ERROR: failed to do request: Head "https://pdr.akamai.com/v2/library/tomcat9-java11/manifests/platform-2.19.4-RELEASE": dial tcp 127.10.0.28:443: connect: connection refused
------
 > [internal] load metadata for pdr.akamai.com/library/tomcat9-java11:platform-2.19.4-RELEASE:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://pdr.akamai.com/v2/library/tomcat9-java11/manifests/platform-2.19.4-RELEASE": 
dial tcp 127.10.0.28:443: connect: connection refused
```

It looked like the server was not reachable from my machine.

However when I tried curl command with verbose option, it's the same IP address that dns resolves to and I get a response.

Following is the output of curl command

```
❯ curl --verbose https://pdr.akamai.com/v2/library/tomcat9-java11/manifests/platform-2.19.4-RELEASE
*   Trying 127.10.0.28:443...
* Connected to pdr.akamai.com (127.10.0.28) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Massachusetts; L=Cambridge; O=Akamai Technologies; CN=pdr.akamai.com
*  start date: Oct 26 12:53:44 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 12:53:44 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "pdr.akamai.com" matched cert's "pdr.akamai.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Massachusetts; L=Cambridge; O=Akamai Technologies; OU=KMI; CN=kdc_ca.2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v2/library/tomcat9-java11/manifests/platform-2.19.4-RELEASE HTTP/1.1
> Host: pdr.akamai.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2023 09:00:20 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Content-Length: 34915
< Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws
< Docker-Content-Digest: sha256:98be2134cf221dc1bdb43a65cf7d7ce49a748ef02ad95e52fc6f999484f1cb91
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Etag: "sha256:98be2134cf221dc1bdb43a65cf7d7ce49a748ef02ad95e52fc6f999484f1cb91"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<
```

I tried flushing the DNS cache and still the issue remains. Is there some configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be some issue with docker. I uninstalled docker completely including all config files and reinstalled it again. It's working now.